# SELECT from data_base utf-8_bin data purified

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, utf-8

All I want is to `SELECT` an `utf8_bin` string stored in an table with 2 rows

1 `id` and 2 `continut` first is an `int(20) NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT` and second is `VARCHAR(2000) utf8_bin NOT NULL` used for Romanian language inserts.

The data is stored correct whe i acces it from phpmyadmin, but on `echo` it returns strange characters instead romanian diacritics.

```
$sqlis = "SELECT continut FROM cantari WHERE id = {$id}";
$dbh->query($sqlis);
foreach ($dbh->query($sqlis) as $liniie);

$continut = $liniie['continut'];
```

This is the result: `Cau?i r�uri ?i izvoare`

`$continut` is my data from sql. I've setted meta on file as utf8 `<meta charset="utf-8">` in header's content.

Can htaccess help me or css? or how to replace that elements with the normal Romanian diacritics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sqlis = "SELECT continut FROM cantari WHERE id = {$id}; SET NAMES 'utf8' ";
```

So all we need is to specify in SQL server side that we will use utf8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the character set to UTF-8 on the Mysql connection?

For example:

```
$dbh->set_charset("utf8")
```

Without it, the data returned from MySQL will be translated to Cp1252. Any chars that don't fit in Cp1252 will be set to "?".

Comment: I solved the problem, but that is not correct answer, so i will post them for others in my situation. Thankyou for you enlightning!

Comment: @DomutaMarcel According to the PHP manual, this is the correct way over using `SET NAMES`. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php